# For what values of $k$ does the matrix have given eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For what values of $k$ does the matrix
 $$\mathbf{A} =  \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1&k\\ 1&1\end {array}
 \right] $$
 have eigenvalues $\lambda = 0.5, 1.5$?

I have tried to write out the determinant of $\lambda \mathbf{I}_2 - \mathbf{A}$: $(\lambda - 1)(\lambda - 1)-k$. To find the eigenvalues, this determinant should be equal to $0$. In other words, you solve the characteristic polynomial $(\lambda - 1)(\lambda - 1)-k = 0$. I just do not know 1) if this even is the correct/optimal approach to solve the question, 2) if it actually is, how to move forward?

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable approach. You can just plug in $\lambda=0.5$ and solve for $k$, and then verify that it also works for $\lambda=1.5$.

Comment: Hmm something goes wrong. It just does not add up to me. Can you possibly show it as an answer? That would help a lot and I would accept it :)

Comment: If I plug in $\lambda=0.5$, I get $k=0.25$. Plugging in $\lambda=1.5$ gives $0.25-k=0$, so that value of $k$ works for both.

Comment: I don't know why this question was down-voted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Alex R.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/22064/alex-r) said, your approach is perfectly reasonable.

The eigenvalues satisfy $(\lambda-1)(\lambda-1)-k=0$; i.e., $\lambda^2-2\lambda+(1-k)=0$.

If you want them to be $1.5$ and $0.5$, then $(\lambda-1.5)(\lambda-0.5)=\lambda^2-2\lambda+0.75=0$.

To make these the same, set $1-k=0.75$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ah thanks. But is there only one unique number of $k$ that gives these eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, the product of the eigenvalues ($0.75$) is the determinant $(1-k)$

Comment: That is what I get but the phrasing of the question mentions "values" instead of "value"

Comment: Ahh thanks. Timing :))